# How to run a Azure DataBricks Notebook and get it's result via Rest API

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-rest-api

I have a use case where I need to run a set of notebooks developed in Azure Databricks (that performs several queries and calculations), but the end user (non-technical) needs only the final result, displayed in a web page.

I searched the Azure Databricks APIs but didn't find anything about programmatically running (and getting the results) of notebooks.

Did someone already performed some task like that?

Is there a REST API that allows developers to execute Azure Databricks Notebooks (or some kind of Library for Node.js)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's covered by the [Jobs REST API:](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html)

You can execute notebook:

- either by creating a [new job](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsCreate) (you need `notebook_task`) and then triggering the [new job run](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunNow)
- or creating a [single run](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunsSubmit) (also called RunSubmit) - also `notebook_task`

In either case, you will get a run ID, and then you need to wait until job is finished (checking the `state` via [get run API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunsGet) until it's get `life_cycle_state` equal to `TERMINATED`), and then retrieve the [output of the run](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunsGetOutput)

Comment: Thanks Alex! I'll try it tomorrow with the team, and I'll let you know the result.